# Shifting/Migrating PHP Codeigniter project to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Our Company has a Software Product consists of Web App, Android and iOS App.
we have more then 350 clients, that is we have more then 350 databases(MYSQL) of each client and one code file repository(PHP Codeigniter). When new client purchase our software we just copy the the old empty database and client is able to use the software. this is our architecture.
Now we are planing to shift to AWS but we do not know which AWS service we really need for this type of architecture
We have Codeigniter 3.1 version, PHP 7 and MYSQL.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this sort of system on a single EC2 instance, simply installing the same software as you have on your current server. However in this case you are likely better off to host it somewhere cheaper than AWS.

However, what I recommend is that you implement it using RDS, EC2, S3 and Cloudfront.

**RDS**

I recommend to run your database on RDS:

- the database server competes over completely different resources than PHP, so if you run into performance problems, it is impossible to figure out what is happening when database and PHP are on the same instance. A lack of CPU can lead to a lack of memory and vice versa.
- built-in point-in-time recovery for up to 35 days has saved my bacon many many times and is great when you have a bug that is hard to reproduce or when someone (you) has accidentally deleted a large amount of data

On top of this I recommend to also go for Aurora for MySQL instead of MySQL RDS, especially as I expect your database size on disk to be smaller than 50GB:

- On MySQL RDS you need to commission at least 100GB of disk to get good enough performance for production. 100GB gives you 100x50kb per second on the EBS disks that are used.
- By comparison, on AWS Aurora you get the read performance of 6 different storage locations without having to commit to any amount of disk space. This saves money and is more performant
- Aurora is also much faster in restoring point in time as well as with "dumb" queries, ie. table scans.

**EC2**

- I recommend to look at nothing older than the t3, c5 or m5 instances, as they have the new "nitro hypervisor" and are significantly faster, while being cheaper. From experience you can go down a notch from your existing CPU count with these instances
- If you can use c6/m6/t4 instances
- I also found c5a and equivalents to be just as performant
- AWS recommends to always use auto-scaling, but if you are coming a single server somewhere else you are already winning because you can restore within minutes.
- Once you hit $600 per month in EC2 charges, definitely look at autoscaling. Virtually every webapp can be written in a way that allows for a server to be replaced at any point in time. With auto scaling you can then use Spot instances at 50-90% discount for your 2nd/3rd etc instance and save serious money.

**S3**

Store all customer provided files on S3, DO NOT get into a shared file system.

- This is much cheaper than any disk or file system and has numerous automation features, such as versioning, cross-region backup, archiving, event triggers etc.
- do not ever make your bucket publicly accessible.

**Cloudfront**

The key benefit of storing all customer provided files on S3 is that you can serve them with Cloudfront without paying for CPU. Cloudfront only charges for traffic delivered. S3 only charges for space used. Every file delivered through Cloudfront does not use your server's CPU, sockets, network bandwidth. On top of this transfer from EC2 to S3 and from S3 to Cloudfront is free of charge. You are only charged for the traffic you already had to pay for anyway.

You need to secure your clients file properly with Signed Urls or Signed Cookies. For this you can either create separate S3 buckets for each client or one single bucket.

**Bonus: SQS**

Many things in web application do not need to be done right now. They can wait a bit, sometimes a couple of 100 milliseconds, sometimes minutes or hours.

Anything that can wait, I recommend start implementing a background process that reads from an SQS queue for it. Your web application will need minimal time to push the work required and its parameters into an SQS queue. Your background process can then work on it in (rough) order of entry into the queue. When you use your normal web servers to process the background queues you are already getting a better distribution of server load over time. This is because you cannot control the amount of web requests, but you can control the speed in how you process background items (to a degree of course).
Later, when you have a lot of background processing and a lot of traffic, you can consider using different servers for background processing.
There are also lots of ways of how you can hook other event driven code onto the items that go into your queue, including monitoring for limits exceeded for certain items etc.